# How To Include jquery and script in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I want to put datepicker in my angular2.I have refer to other questions here and my code is still not working. I would like to know what is the proper way to include jquery (datepicker).

**html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles/glDatePicker.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="glDatePicker.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function()
        {
            $('mydate').glDatePicker();
        });
    </script>


    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text"> Date </label>
       <div class="col-md-4">
            <input #date1 type="text" id="mydate" name="date1" class="form-control" formControlName="date1">

   </div>
</html>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Form, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';   



@Component({
    selector: 'add',
    templateUrl: 'app/add.html',


    //styleUrls:['app/styles/glDatePicker.default.css']

})

export class AddComponent {


    AddForm: FormGroup;   

    date1: FormControl;

}
```

SO it is not working. even my html page shows nothing.What should I do in component file? do I need to install anything?
tq

Comment: Is it compiling without errors? If yes, any errors in your console?

Comment: no error , it shows nothing, not even my html

Comment: can you create plunkr for this ?